# Set onItemClickListener on custom inflated layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I'm inflating linearlayouts in a linear layout, by doing this:

```
    LinearLayout parent = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_parent)); 


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        View r = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.main_item, parent, false);
        ImageView itemBg = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_img);
        TextView title = (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_title);
        TextView time = (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_time);
        TextView persons = (TextView) r
                .findViewById(R.id.main_item_persons);
        String imgLink = withoTechnics.get(i).getImage_1()
                .replace("[HEIGHT]", parent.getHeight() + "")
                .replace("[WIDTH]", (int) parent.getWidth() / 3 + "");
        Log.v("--", imgLink);
        title.setText(withoTechnics.get(i).getTitle());
        time.setText(withoTechnics.get(i).getPreparation_time());
        persons.setText(withoTechnics.get(i).getPersons() + "");
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgLink, itemBg);
        parent.addView(r);
    }
```

Now can I set on item click listener by executing this code, or what I need to modify so I can set the onitemclicklistener for these objects?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I suggest that you switch to a ListView with a custom adapter.

- Then you could change the getView method of the adapter, to implement
  all your `TextView`'s and `ImageView`'s into a list item.
- And for the clicks you could implement
  `listView.setOnItemClickListener()`.

Here's a basic tutorial on how to create a 
[ListView with a custom adapter](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html).

Comment: No I want one listener so I can get the item that is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You have an object of textview with below code:

```
TextView persons = (TextView) r
            .findViewById(R.id.main_item_persons);
```

So like any other events you can add click event's to this textview.

```
persons .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Toast.makeText(context,"textview person clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```